# Why are these parentheses surrounding a single variable when not casting, declaring or changing associativity?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I was looking at some code used in an embedded environment and stumbled upon this snippet:

```
...MACRO_VALUE+(value)/4*4
```

where `MACRO_VALUE` and `value` come from:

```
  #define MACRO_VALUE 0x...
  #define MACRO_FUNCTION(value, priority) ...MACRO_VALUE+(value)/4*4...
```

Every time `value` and `priority` from `MACRO_FUNCTION` are used they are surrounded by parentheses.`value` and `priority` are `uint32_t` types. I tested a version with and without parentheses but the result stays the same. I searched on stackoverflow but couldn't find anything so far. As I see no casting, declaration, modification of evaluation order or associativity I don't understand the purpose of those parentheses. What is their purpose?

Comment: Consider e.g. `MACRO_FUNCTION(1+1, 0)`.

Comment: Prefer inline functions instead of learning from this snippet though.

Comment: This is addressed by every beginner-level C programming book, usually at the same place where it introduces `#define` and explains function-like macros.